# How to assign Role to user on ASP.NET 4.5 MVC app

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, user-roles

I created MVC web app using ASP.NET 4.5 Templates. In Web.config, I changed the SQL Connection string to point my existing SQL Server database.

I run the project and created necessary tables into my SQL Server Database. I also create a new user.

My first questions is how to create a **user role**?
And my Second question is how to use “Roles” to give respected permission to my user to access only certain part of my app?

Kind Regards,

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: http://www.asp.net/ is the place to start for tutorials and how-to's

Comment: Thanks @Roman. Is it possible for you to share a specific link for my questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Ok. Here is how to created roles.**

I am using VS2015 and ASP.NET 4.5 MVC. I use **Microsoft Asp.Net 4.5 identity** for authentication.

(**context.Roles.Add(new icrosoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole()**)

So in my Model **Role.cs**:

```
// POST: /Roles/Create
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection collection)
{
    try
    {
        context.Roles.Add(new Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole()
        {
            Name = collection["RoleName"]
        });
        context.SaveChanges();
        ViewBag.ResultMessage = "Role created successfully !";
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

And I also put below code top of my every controller respectivly:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "TestRole")]
```